# Make consecutive button clicks async

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to make it so that consecutive button clicks happen asynchronously in react native.

```
  onclick = async () => {
    await this.f();
  }

  async f() {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
    });
    let result = await promise; 
    console.log(result); // "done!"
  }

 <TouchableOpacity
   onPress={() => this.onclick ()}
   style={styles.headerButton}
   >
     <Text style={styles.headerButtonButtonText}>Edit</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

With this code, clicking a button multiple times a second results in "done!" being logged much less than every second

Comment: For clarification, when you say click multiple times, do you mean click 1+ per second?

Comment: Yes, update the post

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in this snippet. I think your problem is that you `await this.f()` on the `onclick` function but `this.f()` does not actually return a promise.

```js
let f = async () => {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });
  let result = await promise; 
  console.log(result); // "done!"
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.25/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="f()">click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the behavior I don't want. I want the done! message to be spaced out every second.

Comment: I think any `async` function returns a promise, so `this.f()` should be a promise

Comment: @BiggerD it is spaced out every second from when you clicked the button... you should probably be more specific with what you want